# Google Data Studio - Is it possible to filter across data sources

Tags: looker-studio

I have seen the link below which explains that it is possible to create a filter on one field between sources by generating a calculated field and then assigning the same field ID to both fields for filtering purposes:

[Using the same filter control for two different data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752214/using-the-same-filter-control-for-two-different-data-sources)

But my question is whether or not it is possible to make that particular field (that is now shared between 2 data sources) dependent on other filters that are tied to 1 of the data sources?

Example would be:

- One dataset with country name and city name
- One dataset with city name and population
- I've generated a calculated field to be able to filter on city name since they now share the same field_id.
- What I'd like to do is use a control that selects country from dataset 1 and then automatically filters city_name in both datasets.

I realize I could just pull country name into my dataset in the example above, but in my real dataset there are a significant number of fields I'd be looking to be able to use for filters.

Answer (score -1):

If a filter is set, all charts and filters are updated with that setting. However, it would be a huge mess, if any of these objects would automatically changes the filters again. Then all object would be updated again and the filter setting could be changed once more, thus ending up in an infinity loop.

Therefore, a filter can only apply to a field. If this should cause further filtering an user action is needed. It would be possible to write a customer vizualisation, which would mimic an user action, but again it could end in an infinity loop.