# Filter only filters data from one data source google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Data Studio report that has several graphs from different data sources (re: google sheets).

Each graph is coming from different data source. But both of these data sources has one common field called ID. Then, I want for the same filter to control both of my graphs.

I've already tried this post that said I need to make a new Column using function in Google Data Studio consist of the same ID.

[Using the same filter control for two different data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752214/using-the-same-filter-control-for-two-different-data-sources)

But still my data can't be filtered, any idea how to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for data from Big Query and Cloud Storage. In these cases the field of to datasets are filtered, if they have the same name. For calculated field the id has to be the same.