# How can I filter related records in Google Data Studio from multiple data sources using a filter on a field only available in one of the data sources?

Tags: looker-studio

I have two data sources. Both data sources have a different schema but do share one `ID` field.

**`DS1`**

| ID | Name | Age | Country | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | anchal | 23 | US | 7.666666667 |
| 2 | nigam | 10 | CA | 5 |
| 3 | dingo | 20 | UK | 3.333333333 |

**`DS2`**

| DS1 ID | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | BBB |
| 1 | CCC | DDD |
| 1 | EEE | FFF |
| 3 | GGG | HHH |
| 3 | III | JJJ |

The `DS1 ID` field from `DS2` is from `DS1.ID`.

I will have both of these as a table in a Google Data Studio report. Then I will add a filter on `DS1.Country`. This will obviously filter the `DS1` table.

I want it to also filter on `DS2` based on the matching `DS2.DS1 ID` rows against `ID` from `DS1`.

So, for example, if someone selects `UK` in the `DS1.Country` filter then this is what the report would show:

**`DS1.Country` Filter**

- `[ ] US`
- `[ ] CA`
- `[x] UK`

**`DS1`**

| ID | Name | Age | Country | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | dingo | 20 | UK | 3.333333333 |

**`DS2`**

| DS1 ID | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | GGG | HHH |
| 3 | III | JJJ |

I know how to filter two different data sources **against the same field** as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752214/using-the-same-filter-control-for-two-different-data-sources) but that is not what I am trying to do.

**Sample data**:

- Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eSdGhwSt-B7Odsb3Sa9e7VRfgIHNLj7pFmL_LHzp87w/edit?usp=sharing)) for both [`DS1`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eSdGhwSt-B7Odsb3Sa9e7VRfgIHNLj7pFmL_LHzp87w/edit#gid=0) and [`DS2`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eSdGhwSt-B7Odsb3Sa9e7VRfgIHNLj7pFmL_LHzp87w/edit#gid=1488809277)
- [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ed14290a-1a56-418b-8bba-385ac5cb1fc2) report with these sources and a filter on `Country`. The Country filter only filters the top table. I want it to filter the bottom table based on the IDs visible in the top table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420) the respective `ID` fields in both data sources and then use a [fixed-size list](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335992) [control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) to show the `Country` values; to filter the data to show all records for `UK` set the [default selection](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335992#:%7E:text=by%20this%20control.-,Default%20selection,-Specify%20default%20values) to `UK` (or select as required):

### 1) Blend Fields

| Description | Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Data Source**: | DS1 | DS2 |
| **Dimension 1**: | `ID` | `DS1 ID` |
| **Dimension 2**: | `Name` | `Make` |
| **Dimension 3**: | `Age` | `Model` |
| **Dimension 4**: | `Country` |  |
| **Dimension 5**: | `temp` |  |
| **Image**: | [image: table_2] | [image: table_2] |

### 2) Join Configuration

| Join Description | Table 1 Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **Join Operator**: | Left Outer |
| **Join Condition 1**: | `ID (Table 1)` `DS1 ID (Table 2)` |
| **Image**: | [image: join_configuration] |

This will result in a blend with 7 fields:

| Fields |
| --- |
| `Name` |
| `Country` |
| `Make` |
| `Model` |
| `ID` |
| `Age` |
| `temp` |

### 3) Fixed-size list Control

[image: 8]

| Description | Field |
| --- | --- |
| **Control Field**: | `Country` |
| **Default Selection**: | `UK` (leave blank to view all values by default) |
| **Metric**: **Aggregation**: | `ID` [`AVG`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518) |

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/8b94a118-1080-4653-8b55-030cfe50dd26) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oc-nAfR9w3H0sitnw5tG5sHesLDtjS9YZmjcEPDPIVo/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 12]